Why can't I seem to install PostgreSQL on Windows 11?
I want to update my PostgreSQL version from 16.2 to 17.
I have uninstalled the old version, removed postgre folder, and deleted local temp. But, every time I install new version, I found this error.
Error running C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_75822716a3\getlocales.exe: Program ended with an error exit code


Try manually installing the required version of MSVC Redistributable

Any hints in the installation logfile?
